# Unioning two families of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I am supposed to show the following result, which is quite basic but I cannot find a proof.  I am wondering if anyone knows a proof or can provide a reference for where such a result may have been stated?

Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$ be any two families of sets from the power set of $n$ elements ($[n]$).  Then, given the set $\mathcal{H}$ defined as
$$
\mathcal{H} = \{F \cup G: F \in \mathcal{F}, G \in \mathcal{G}\},
$$
I need to show that $|\mathcal{H}| \geq |\mathcal{G}|$ whenever $|\mathcal{F}| > |\mathcal{G}|$.

Comment: Maybe you should try finding a counterexample instead.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have and am unable to find a counterexample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $n=3$ we can take $\mathcal F = \Big\{\{3\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}\Big\}$ and $\mathcal G = \Big\{\{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}\Big\}$ to get $\mathcal H = \Big\{\{1,2,3\}\Big\}$. Then $|\mathcal F| > |\mathcal G| > |\mathcal H|$.